# Java libGDX Black bars with ExtendViewport using

Tags: java, android, graphics, libgdx, viewport

According to [documentation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) the `ExtendViewport`should extend the view and keep the aspect ratio, but whenever I try Implemented this viewPort Ive got two bars in the side of the phone screen. [image] (this is sample background image,with some text and button on it  to check how stretch will be).

Code:

```
 public class Overlap2d extends Game {
public static  float ASPECT_RATIO ;
public static final int GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH = 40;
public static final int GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT = 80;

@Override
public void create () {
    ASPECT_RATIO=(float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/(float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() ;
    ScreenManager.getScreenManager().init(this);
    ScreenManager.getScreenManager().showScreen( ScreenName.MAIN_MENU );
}}

public abstract class AbstractScreen extends Stage implements Screen {

public AbstractScreen() {
    super(new ExtendViewport(GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH,GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT,new OrthographicCamera()));
}
public abstract void buildStage();
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    super.act(delta);
    super.draw();
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
getViewport().update(width,height);
}
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
@Override
public void resume() {}
@Override
public void pause() {}
@Override
public void hide() {}}



public class MenuScreen extends AbstractScreen{
private Texture txtrBg;
public MenuScreen() {
    super();
    txtrBg   = new Texture( Gdx.files.internal("test.png") );
}

@Override
public void buildStage() {

    getCamera().position.set(GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    Image bg = new Image(txtrBg);
    bg.setSize(GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH,GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    bg.setPosition(0,0);
    addActor(bg);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    txtrBg.dispose();

}}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior, just like the documentation says. The green bars are the extra ("extended") area where you haven't drawn anything yet. What do you want to happen?

Comment: They writing that this viewport avoid the black bars. "Here is an example of using ExtendViewport. The stage's size of 640x480 is first scaled to fit without changing the aspect ratio, then the stage's shorter dimension is increased to fill the screen. The aspect ratio is not changed and there are no black bars, but the stage may be longer in one direction."

Comment: Yes, but the bars you see are because you didn't draw anything in that area. The black bars the documentation are talking about are areas where you can't draw anything. In that case your scene is cropped.

Comment: hmm thats weird because I setting my background size like GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH,GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT so I assumed that it will fill all the screen? Also whenever I setting up my viewport as extended viewport my labels,buttons, bitmap font etc. are blured and not sharp enought, but the textures seems to scale fine, maybe you know how can I handle it?

Comment: A StretchViewport does that, but then the scene is distorted.

Comment: Okay so maybe you can help me what background resolution is the best for a background images(in portraite mode )? I want to adjust it for most of phone screen size and keep the ratio and avoid green screens

Comment: In my opinion, for most types of games it is best to use approximately 1.6:1 ratio virtual size (the dimensions you pass to the ExtendViewport constructor) and then draw a background that is bigger than that in both dimensions so it is enough that you are covering the extra area that might be added on any screen from 4:3 to 18.5:9. Then you know it is safe to put any gameplay within your virtual dimensions and it will be visible on any device.

Comment: hmmm Ive always obtain the undrawed borders on every screen I tested no matter what resolution of image is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int GAME_SCREEN_WIDTH = 40;
public static final int GAME_SCREEN_HEIGHT = 80;
```

you're using width and height ratio 1:2 but only very view device fits in this ratio so why don't you try 48 and 80 as viewport width and height.

Question is almost same so explanation can fit here also

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43398153/3445320